# What is the correct way to configure custom mapper for WebApplicationException?

Tags: exception, jersey, dropwizard

I've created class that implements `implements ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>` and registered it by `environment.addProvider(new WebApplicationExceptionMapper());`. My custom mapper works but only for some exceptions extended from `WebApplicationException`. For example it doesn't work for `ConflictException` and it also doesn't work for my custom exceptions with following constructor:

```
public ConflictException(URI location, Object entity) {
    super(Response.status(Response.Status.CONFLICT).location(location).entity(entity).build());
}
```

It will work if I'll remove `super(Response.status....`. This is very strange and I can't explain this. I'm not sure is it `Jersey` or `Dropwizard` behaviour.

What is correct way to configure mapper for all `WebApplicationException` and subclasses? Can you explain problems that I have?

Comment: Hint : dropwizard have it default exception mapper. And there is no specific order in which the mappers are registered. So sometime your mapper will work and other time it may not. An idea is to remove dropwizards exception mapper. [This article](http://thoughtspark.org/2013/02/25/dropwizard-and-jersey-exceptionmappers/) may help you.

Comment: Yes, I've already done it but it doesn't help

Comment: it may help : https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/710

Answer (score 5):

May be a little too late, but found this to work.

> for dropwizard 0.8 and above

in the yaml configuration

```
server:
    registerDefaultExceptionMappers: false
```

This would disable the DWs default exception mapper, then add your own exception mappers

```
// Register the custom ExceptionMapper(s)
    environment.jersey().register(new RestErrorsHandler());
```

Source: [github issue](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/215)

Comment: what is the fix for dropwizard < 0.8?

Comment: doesn't work while im currently trying to use it in 1.0.0-rc3

Answer (score 0):

This post shows how to create custom ExceptionMappers:

http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/

Perhaps this post could also help, if you having problems with your custom exceptionMappers:
http://thoughtspark.org/2013/02/25/dropwizard-and-jersey-exceptionmappers/